# Proof of the optimality of A* algorithm

Tags: algorithms

In the original paper of A* algorithm, [*A Formal Basis for the Heuristic Determination of Minimum Cost Paths*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=a%20formal%20basis%20for%20the%20heuristic%20determination%20of%20minimum%20cost%20paths&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://fai.cs.uni-saarland.de/teaching/winter12-13/heuristic-search-material/Astar.pdf&ei=m-NRUeOUMYa0kAXpgIHIDw&usg=AFQjCNFp9yfCwE0_B_epYI4kPmEmZjOGww&bvm=bv.44342787,d.dGI), the author proved the optimality of A* in *Theorem 2*, page 105.

However, I cannot understand the proof. The assumption is that we have a node in $G_s$ which is not expanded by algorithm $A$, but in the proof we change the graph to $G_{n,\theta}$, isn't it a problem?

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper handy?

Comment: In questions like this, you should always post a link to the paper,... the question is not general enough to consider that self-contained, plus you're referring to a particular proof

Comment: @muzzlator, I edited by post.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis, thank you, I have edited by post.